# How can I overcome java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Where the IMAGE FILES are in XML code not used in Activity.Getting error in only some devices

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-bitmap

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 253513236 byte allocation with 16774816 free bytes and 163MB until OOM

Hello, everyone, I am new to I am developing a game in android in which I am using images for the start button, for background, for how to play button and some images on activity. However, I reduced the image size from 800kbs to 35 kb 85kb so far but encountering with this error.so far I had searched about this error on internet I got many solutions but NOT GOT EXACTLY FOR THIS.
Here is my log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vikaskonaparthi.game, PID: 23126
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 253513236 byte allocation with 16774816 free bytes 
and 163MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
    at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2952)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2684)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:398)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.vikaskonaparthi.game.Start.onCreate(Start.java:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1398)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Here is my Activity

```
public class Start extends AppCompatActivity {

private SoundPlayer sound;
AdView mAdview;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    MobileAds.initialize (this, getString (R.string.admob_app_id));
    mAdview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitialAd=new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("");
    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Start.this,Character.class));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("");
    AppRate.with(this)
            .setInstallDays(1)
            .setLaunchTimes(3)
            .setRemindInterval(2)
            .monitor();

    AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Start.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Start.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Start.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Start.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }



}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults){
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Start.this,
                       Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){ 
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
public void startGame(View view)
{

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.click);//To play music in onCreate
    mp.start();
    if(interstitialAd.isLoaded())
    {
        interstitialAd.show();
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Character.class));
    }
}
public void aboutGame(View view)
{

    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.click);//To play music in onCreate
    mp.start();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class));
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
            finish();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

Here is XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Start"
android:gravity="bottom|center"
android:background="@drawable/b1"
android:weightSum="12">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pac"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/strawberry"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cherries"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ene"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ene2"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:onClick="startGame"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_start"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/About"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:onClick="aboutGame"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_about"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="" />


</LinearLayout>
```

ANY help would be appreciated I am trying to resolve it from more than a week.

I don't know what I have to do now I am stuck with this thing. But this error is not showing in Samsung and Nokia device running on 9 and 10 versions, only getting an error on Mi and Vivo devices I think they are running on below android 9 version. Any Help will be appreciated. As this is a game If I use large_heap=true in manifest making the movement slow down.

Comment: It's trying to allocate 250MB of ram, so it probably isn't the picture itself. You must be loading images or other data in a loop somewhere. For example creating a lot of bitmaps over and over again. If that's the case you should try to reuse existing bitmaps instead of creating new ones

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory#inBitmap for further reading on how to manage bitmaps

Comment: I had the same problems because:



* I used high resulution images (more pixel than needed) Example: a 512x256 pixel image with 16 bit colors need about 250 MB of uncompressed image when beeing displayed even though the compressed jpg file is much smaller


* in adapter classes i loaded images by code without releasing the previous image.

Without seeing the code it is not possible to solve you problem

Comment: There is complete code

Comment: As of now I had found that error is causiing due to gif images i am using in this game. 
 pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView Can I have solution atleast now.